# Typescript array of all class property keys and value type pair

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

For context I'm trying to see if this is possible for Typescript.
Assuming a class with 2 properties like this.

```
class Todo {
  name: string = "";
  isDone: boolean = false;

  toJson() {
    return {
      name: this.name,
      isDone: this.isDone
    };
  }

  static fromJson(json: Todo) {
    const todo = new Todo();
    Object.assign(todo, json);
    return todo;
  }
}

class TodoStore {
 todos: Todo[] = [];
 someOtherProp: boolean = false;
}
```

I want to create a method with the type signature that accomplishes the code below and still have typesafety (replacing the `any` types).

```
interface PropertyConverter<T> {
  key: keyof T;
  convertTo: (prop: any) => any;
  convertFrom: (prop: any) => any;
}

function createStorageAdapter<T>(target: T, properties: PropertyConverter<T>[]) {
  // Code goes here
}

// Usage
const store = new TodoStore();
const adapter = createStorageAdapter(store, [
 {
   key: "todos",
   convertTo: (todos) => todos.map(x => x.toJson()), // todos should be instances of class Todo[]
   convertFrom: (todos) => todos.map(x => Todo.fromJson(x)), // todos should be a json array
 },
 {
  key: "someOtherProp",
  convertTo: (prop) => prop ? 1 : 0,
  convertFrom: (prop) => prop === 1 ? true : false
 }
]);
```

I'm trying to see if it's possible to have an array of objects where the `key` property is a property of a class and the `serialize` `prop` argument type is the the type of that class property.

So in this case if I have an object like

```
{
  key: "todos",
  convertTo: todos => functionThatConvertsAnArrayOfTodoAsPlainJson(todos),
  convertFrom: todos => functionThatConvertsToAnArrayOfTodoClasses(todos)
}
```

Key would correspond to the `Todo[]` property of class `TodoStore` and the argument on `convertTo` would be the type of that property, which is `Todo[]` in this case. Lastly `convertFrom` would be the type of whatever's the result of `convertTo`. I easily can do this using `any`, but wanted to know if it's possible to have proper typings for the `convertTo` and `convertFrom`.

Comment: I'm, not sure what you expect. Please fix all syntax errors in your example

Comment: Updated the question and added more context as well as cleaned up the syntax errors. Hopefully it's clearer now.